# sencha touch 2 container draggable?

Tags: sencha-touch, scrollable, ext.list

I extend a Ext.List and want to **disable** the container draggale (like pullrefresh) and retain scrollable, the config is `draggable:false,scrollable:true`,however that does not work,is that a sencha touch bug or i am not understand the config,can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

my question is called overscrolling,using this config:

```
scrollable : {
      momentumEasing:  {
         momentum: {
           acceleration: 30,
           friction: 0.5
         },
         bounce: {
            acceleration: 0.0001,
            springTension: 0.9999,
         },
         minVelocity: 5
      },
      outOfBoundRestrictFactor: 0   
      }
```